# Web service URL for ComIbmWSRequestNode

Tags: messagebroker

Any reason for why executing this shows the web service URL for ComIbmSOAPRequestNode but not for ComIbmWSRequestNode?

```
mqsireportproperties MYBROKER -o AllMessageFlows -e default -r
```

I'm using MB6.1 and I have a requirement to extract all hardcoded URLs of HTTP nodes that vary between two environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could raise a requirement here to try to get the property added:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/?PROD_ID=532

It is almost certainly jsut an oversight, but, given that 6.1 is almost out of support you may find that an RFE will not be accepted, or even if it is it will be targeted to a future release.

The embedded EG level listener outputs it's URI registrations with the following command:

mqsireportproperties  -e  -o HTTP(S)Connector -r

So if you could temporarily swith the http nodes to use the EG level listener using:

mqsichangeproeprties  -e  -o ExecutionGroup -n httpNodesUseEmbeddedListener -v true

Then mqsireportproperties will give you what you need.

Otherwise I think the best bet is writing a small CMP app that examines the flows that are deployed looking for SOAP and HTTP Input Nodes and extract the property that way.